# Centrally apply a GPO rule to Local Admins

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

Pardon if someone asked before - tried searching maybe I missed it out.

Anyways, I have to

1a) Set a domain wide policy to Deny Access to this Computer from the Network
1b) Put each computer's local "Administrator" in that policy

Where I'm stumped is that on the Domain Controller >> Group Policy Management, while changing the policies during the please Select Users and Computers phase, it only displays domain users. Can't do a scope change either - it only allows searching the local DC, the whole domain, or the forest

I did some research on Restricted Users, sure I can use that tool to overwrite users group memberships but that's about it, I can't automate adding / centrally manage each PC's local admin to the Deny Logon policy.

I'd value any ideas or alternative suggestions to this issue. Might have to explain to management or even go thorough the sticky way of simply doing this as out of the box default for new computers

Answer (score 2):

You can just enter the name of the user account. It does not need to resolve.

You may also use the "Local account and member of Administrators group" special identity.

[image: Local account and member of Administrators group]

FYI, if Network Level Authentication is used, the account will not be able to logon using remote desktop.

Comment: Many thanks, I read somewhere it was "NT AUTHORITY\Local account and member of Administrators group" but just "Local account and member of Administrators group" works. 'Lokales Konto und Mitglied der Gruppe "Administratoren"' in german, with local search path (computer rather than domain) does not work because of the quotes. I just copy/pasted english version and it works fine.

Comment: Group "Administratoren" also was necessary.